# Прозрачный фон выбранной строки в tableview

Tags: xcode, objective-c

У меня прозрачная таблица с кнопками, которые занимают не все пространство строки. Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на строку кнопка подствечивалась, а строка оставалась прозрачной.
Сейчас либо я отключаю Selection, и тогда строка остается прозрачной, но кнопка не подствечивается, либо подсвечивается серым строка.
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor - ничего не меняет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У выделенной строки другой view.

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Так тоже пробовал: ничего не меняется. Цвет выделенной ячейки остается серым.

Comment: Дополнил. Нужно сперва создать view.

Comment: Получилось. Спасибо и ура.